# mailchimp api 3 mc:edits not working (using php)

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Here is the code i'm using for

```
$MailChimp->put("campaigns/".$result['id']."/content", array(
    'template' => array(
        'id' => 249805,//template id
        'sections' => array('name' => 'exapppp', 'content' => 'template part 1'),
    ),
));
```

in response i'm only getting `status='successful'`

but in mail template no changes